# How to carry out HSE06+SOC band structure calculation using VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, hse06

I could not find any good source for this type of calculation. I'd be very appreciated if someone who is experienced with that to show it step by step

Answer (score 15):

I assume that your structure is fully relaxed.

- (I) Self-consistent field calculation at DFT-PBE level with spin-orbit coupling (SOC) to obtain the converged charge density.

  ```
  #SOC related tags:
   LSORBIT=.TRUE.
   SAXIS= 0 0 1
   ISYM=0
  ```
- (II) Usual band calculation at DFT-PBE level with SOC by reading the converged charge density at step I. Note that the k-sampling assigned in KPOINTS can be found in OUTCAR and used in a subsequent step.)

> grep "k-points in reciprocal lattice and weights" OUTCAR -A n (n is the total k points in your band path.)

- (III) Self-consistent field calculation at HSE06 level with SOC by reading the converged charge density at step I.

  ```
  #HSE06 related tags:
   LHFCALC = .TRUE.
   HFSCREEN = 0.2
   ALGO = Damped
   TIME = 0.4
   PRECFOCK=F
  ```
- (IV) Non-self-consistent field calculation at HSE06 level with SOC by reading the converged wave function at step III. ( One special point is we first need to move the IBZKPT at step III to the KPOINTS file and also add the k-points read from OUTCAR at step II to this KPOINTS file with zero weight.)

  ```
  #HSE06 related tags:
   LHFCALC = .TRUE.
   HFSCREEN = 0.2
   ALGO = Normal
   TIME = 0.4
   PRECFOCK=F
  ```
- (V) Read the EIGENVALUE to plot bandstructure (You can make a comparison with the result of step II). Note that the EIGENVALUE from SCF  IBZKPT at step III needs to be excluded. For this step, you may take a look at this post: [How to remove the fake k-points from vasprun.xml file in the calculation of HSE06 band structure?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/how-to-remove-hse06-bandstructure-fake-k-points-from-vasprun-xml-file/3683#3683)
- Ref: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Si_HSE_bandstructure

Comment: Hum, I wouldn't describe step IV as non-self-consistent field (NSCF) calculation since the calculation is still done in a consistent fashion (orbitals, charge density, etc). However, on the note of NSCF calculation with hybrids, I think one could also do a "quick and dirty" run with both orbitals and charge density fixed (`ICHARG=11; ALGO = None`).  From experience, this "one-shot" hybrid calculation could also yield fairly good results. Although the validity of this is to be tested.